# Access Tomcat via tunnel

Tags: apache, tomcat, http-tunneling

I have a problem here that I don't understand (what a surprise). In my infrastructure (all RedHat), there are two member servers behind an Apache load balancer. On each of the member servers, a Tomcat is running on connector port 9080. It may happen that I have to take a server out of the balancing and then call it dedicatedly to test a code change, for example.

Regards

This works:
I call up a local Firefox on the LB server and call up the member server (FQDN + connector port) from there. This works, but is rather slower

What does not work:
I set up a tunnel where the LB is my jump server and the member server is the target server.
Result: HTTP 404

I simply cannot explain this. In principle, I do exactly the same thing, don't I?